# A Python program to convert date to numbers

Tags: python

I want to make a program which takes day, month and year and print them in the format e.g: 
    March 14th, 2016.
I get this error:

```
  File "date.py", line 23
    else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

what is my problem? and how can I fix the code??
this is my code:

```
def get_month_english(month):
    if (month == 1):
        return "January"
    else:
        if (month == 2):
            return "February"
    else:
        if (month == 3):
            return "March"
    else:
        if (month == 4):
            return "April"
    else:
        if (month == 5):
            return "May"
    else:
        if (month == 6):
            return "June"
    else:
        if (month == 7):
            return "July"
    else:
        if (month == 8):
            return "August"
    else:
        if (month == 9):
            return "September"
    else:
        if (month == 10):
            return "October"
    else:
        if (month == 11):
            return "November"
    else:
        return "December"
```

Comment: try elif: instead the python syntax for if should only have a single else: or you need to indent the else statement so they align with the next closest if before it.

Comment: Use `elif`... instead of `else`. Since you're only supposed to have at most 1 else after an if statement

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm

Comment: @rob in python a if-statement **must not** have more then one else clause - see [The if statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement)

Comment: @DahliaSR Sure, if you indent each else with the if above it each if would only have one else clause.. try it. Its UBER ugly, because you would have code that has 12 indentation deep.. but it would be legal.

Comment: @rob that comment was referring to your statement   
> syntax for if **should** only have a single else

Comment: @DahliaSR yep so we are saying the exact same thing :)

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest that instead of using a chain of conditions, that you simply use a list:

```
def get_month_english(month):
    months = [
        "January",
        "February",
        "March",
        "April",
        "May",
        "June",
        "July",
        "August",
        "September",
        "October",
        "November",
        "December"
    ]
    return months[month-1]
```

Or, perhaps a dictionary, so you don't have to subtract 1 to get the correct index:

```
def get_month_english(month):
    months = {
        1: "January",
        2: "February",
        3: "March",
        4: "April",
        5: "May",
        6: "June",
        7: "July",
        8: "August",
        9: "September",
        10: "October",
        11: "November",
        12: "December"
    }
    return months[month]
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be worthwhile to go through this tutorial-

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm

Once you are thorough on the above you should be able to justify the code below

```
def get_month_english(month):
    if (month == 1):
        return "January"
    elif (month == 2):
            return "February"
    elif (month == 3):
            return "March"
    elif (month == 4):
            return "April"
    elif (month == 5):
            return "May"
    elif (month == 6):
            return "June"
    elif (month == 7):
            return "July"
    elif (month == 8):
            return "August"
    elif (month == 9):
            return "September"
    elif (month == 10):
            return "October"
    elif (month == 11):
            return "November"
    else:
        return "December"
```